# python ipv6 to cidr gives wrong mask

Tags: python, ipv6, cidr

I am trying to convert and ipv6 address into cidr format but the netmask appears to be incorrect. It is supposed to be /64 but I get /128

code:

```
import ipaddress
ipv6 = '2001:19f0:5800:8561:5400:ff:fe07:cae5'
iv6cidr = ipaddress.ip_interface(ipv6)
print(iv6cidr)
```

output:

```
2001:19f0:5800:8561:5400:ff:fe07:cae5/128
```

expected output:

```
2001:19f0:5800:8561:5400:ff:fe07:cae5/64
```

I am not an IPv6 wizard but every subnet calculator I find says /64

How do I get the correct IPv6 net mask in cidr format??

ifconfig:

```
vtnet0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=6c03bb<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,JUMBO_MTU,VLAN_HWCSUM,TSO4,TSO6,VLAN_HWTSO,LINKSTATE,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
        ether 56:00:00:07:ca:e5
        inet 108.61.169.203 netmask 0xfffffe00 broadcast 108.61.169.255
        inet6 fe80::5400:ff:fe07:cae5%vtnet0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
        inet6 2001:19f0:5800:8561::64 prefixlen 64
        inet6 2001:19f0:5800:8561:5400:ff:fe07:cae5 prefixlen 64 autoconf
        nd6 options=23<PERFORMNUD,ACCEPT_RTADV,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
        media: Ethernet 10Gbase-T <full-duplex>
        status: active
```

Comment: An IPv6 address does not have an inherent prefix length (with a few exceptions like `::1`). And the same goes for IPv4 addresses since classful addressing was abandoned in the 90s. So you have to give the prefix length / netmask (IPv4) somehow as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /128 is correct. You didn't specify the prefix length in your input so the code had to guess what you meant. The guess it made is the most correct one: a single address as might for example be used on a loopback interface. Showing a /64 would have been an assumption.

Comment: Do you specify the /prefix just like the IPv4 netmask?

Comment: How do you get it to output the assumed /64?

Comment: Explicitly add it to your input address